# Set attr value references without Themes

Tags: android

I would like to set the value resource reference to a style without changing my application or activity themes.

For Example:

**vector.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp", android:width="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24", android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path android:fillColor="?mycolor" android:pathData="8,L5,5L8,1" />
</vector>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
    <attr name="mycolor" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="colorscheme">
        <item name="myColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Another words, how would I set the drawable fillcolor to @color/red?

Comment: as a note, putting " <item name="myColor">@color/red</item> "
inside the theme style tag works. But I would like to use reference attributes without switching themes.